# Is there a way to find if a Field is boolean the same as isPrimitive()?

Tags: java, class, reflection, boolean

Is there a way to find if a Field is `boolean` in Java reflection the same as `isPrimitive()`?

```
Field fieldlist[] = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
for (int i = 0; fieldlist.length & gt; i; i++) {
 Field fld = fieldlist[i];
 if (fld.getClass().isPrimitive()) {
  fld.setInt(object, 0);
  continue;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
if(fld.getType().equals(boolean.class))
```

Just tested this and it works for primitive `boolean` variables.

Answer (score 2):

I believe `Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(fld.getClass())` can be used to determine if the field is a boolean. I haven't had a chance to test whether this works for primitives though.

Comment: This shouldn't work for primitive booleans. If you're using Spring, you can call ClassUtils.isAssignable(Boolean.class, fld.getClass()), though, and that should work if fld is boolean or Boolean.

Comment: Thor84no: I got this error while doing that: The method isAssignableFrom(Class<?>) in the type Class<Boolean> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Boolean)

Comment: Dan Robinson: ClassUtils didn't help either: The method isAssignable(Class<?>, Class<?>) in the type ClassUtils is not applicable for the arguments (Class<Boolean>, 
 Boolean)

Comment: I believe there should be a `boolean.class` that covers primitives (from Java 6 onward I think). You could combine the two `Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(fld.getClass()) || boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(fld.getClass())`. I don't have an IDE handy atm though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.Object%29)):

```
public boolean getBoolean(Object obj)
               throws IllegalArgumentException,
                      IllegalAccessException

Gets the value of a static or instance boolean field.

Parameters:
    obj - the object to extract the boolean value from 
Returns:
    the value of the boolean field 
Throws:
    IllegalAccessException - if the underlying field is inaccessible. 
    IllegalArgumentException - if the specified object is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying field (or a subclass or implementor thereof), **or if the field value cannot be converted to the type boolean** by a widening conversion. 
    NullPointerException - if the specified object is null and the field is an instance field. 
    ExceptionInInitializerError - if the initialization provoked by this method fails.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is for primitive and object:

```
boolean isBooleanType = field.getType().equals(boolean.class) || field.getType().equals(Boolean.class);
```